# How to change the legend text using mschart for R?

Tags: r, mschart

I used mschart to generate a chart in R. However:

(1) I can't find how to change the legend text. Now the legend text is "a" and "b". I hope to change to other string, such as "legend text 1" and "legend text 2".

(2) If I change "a" and "b" to chinese characters, such "中国" and "北京" I got an error. The new word file can't be opened. If I changed back to English characters, it works again!

```r
library(officer)
library(magrittr)
library(mschart)

doc <- read_docx()

newdata <- data.frame(
    Name = c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"), 
    wave_id = c(
         "2017Q1", "2017Q2", "2017Q3", "2017Q4", "2017Q1", "2017Q2", "2017Q3", "2017Q4"
    ), 
    pct = c(0.68,0.71,0.70,0.72,0.57,0.57,0.57,0.58)
)

my_barchart <- ms_barchart(data = newdata, x = "wave_id", y = "pct", group = "Name")
my_barchart <- chart_settings(
    x = my_barchart, dir="horizontal", grouping = "stacked", overlap = 100
)  
my_barchart <- chart_labels(
    my_barchart, title = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL
)
my_barchart <- chart_data_labels(
    my_barchart, position = "ctr", show_val = TRUE,
    separator = ",", show_cat_name = FALSE
)

fp_text_settings <- list(a = fp_text(font.size = 7), b = fp_text(font.size = 7))

my_barchart <- chart_labels_text(my_barchart, fp_text_settings)
mytheme <- mschart_theme(
    axis_title_x = fp_text(color = "red", font.size = 24, bold = TRUE), 
    axis_title_y = fp_text(color = "green", font.size = 12, italic = TRUE),
    grid_major_line_x = fp_border(width = 0, color = "orange"), 
    axis_ticks_y = fp_border(width = 1, color = "orange"))
my_barchart <- set_theme(my_barchart, mytheme)


doc %>% body_add_chart(my_barchart)

print(doc, target = "new.docx")
```

Comment: With the lack of examples on the web I think your best bet is to try and decipher the code of [ms_chart.R](https://github.com/ardata-fr/mschart/blob/master/R/ms_chart.R). Also, [this issue](https://github.com/ardata-fr/mschart/issues/48) might be related.